# How can I import .FAST files more quickly?

Tags: sql-server, fix-protocol

I need to import a large amount of data from .fast files into a database. I have been able to do it using a fast compliant decoder that streams into an application which in turn performs bulk inserts to the database. This works, but not quick enough. Is there a way I can somehow import the data directly from the .fast files without the need for intermediary steps?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And can you post a sample from that "FAST" file?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server SE. Are you looking for encoded?

Comment: Could you give us and example of such ".fast" file?

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?t00eozi571e5ahh

Comment: Can you just post the first 2 or 3 lines of the file in your question, along with some comments about file size, e.g. how many rows in a typical file? And exactly how quickly do you need to load the files?

Comment: The lines are compressed binary in the FIX format. When it's decoded there could be upwards of 30 million lines in a file. I need to be able to do about 1000 of these daily and the whole process can only take 3-4 hours.

Comment: So you need to load 30 billion rows in 4 hours? Have you read Microsoft's [white paper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070(v=sql.100).aspx) on loading performance? And have you profiled your application to identify any bottlenecks? If there are some specific operations that take a lot of time then someone may have a suggestion on how to address them, otherwise it's a fairly broad question.